# How do I format print_r output using multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, html, multidimensional-array

I have a multi dimensional array as follows,

```
$March = array (
    "Friday" => array(
            "1st" => 3,
            "2nd" => 10,
            "3rd" => 17,
            "4th" => 24,
            "5th" => 31 
    ),
    "Saturday" => array (
            "1st" => 4,
            "2nd" => 11,
            "3rd" => 18,
            "4th" => 25 
    ),
    "Sunday" => array (
            "1st" => 5,
            "2nd" => 12,
            "3rd" => 19,
            "4th" => 26 
    ),
    "Monday" => array (
            "1st" => 6,
            "2nd" => 13,
            "3rd" => 20,
            "4th" => 27 
    ),
    "Tuesday" => array (
            "1st" => 7,
            "2nd" => 14,
            "3rd" => 21,
            "4th" => 28 
    ),
    "Wednesday" => array (
            "1st" => 8,
            "2nd" => 15,
            "3rd" => 22,
            "4th" => 29 
    ),
    "Thursday" => array (
            "1st" => 9,
            "2nd" => 16,
            "3rd" => 23,
            "4th" => 30 
    )
```

)

I would like to print the array out in the following format

```
[Friday] => Array ( [1st] => 3 [2nd] => 10 [3rd] => 17 [4th] => 24 [5th] => 31 )
[Saturday] => Array ( [1st] => 4 [2nd] => 11 [3rd] => 18 [4th] => 25 )
[Sunday] => Array ( [1st] => 5 [2nd] => 12 [3rd] => 19 [4th] => 26 )
[Monday] => Array ( [1st] => 6 [2nd] => 13 [3rd] => 20 [4th] => 27 ) 
[Tuesday] => Array ( [1st] => 7 [2nd] => 14 [3rd] => 21 [4th] => 28 )
[Wednesday] => Array ( [1st] => 8 [2nd] => 15 [3rd] => 22 [4th] => 29 ) 
[Thursday] => Array ( [1st] => 9 [2nd] => 16 [3rd] => 23 [4th] => 30 )
```

I can do this by using print_r($March); but it gives me this output

```
Array ( [Friday] => Array ( [1st] => 3 [2nd] => 10 [3rd] => 17 [4th] => 24 [5th] => 31 ) [Saturday] => Array ( [1st] => 4 [2nd] => 11 [3rd] => 18 [4th] => 25 ) [Sunday] => Array ( [1st] => 5 [2nd] => 12 [3rd] => 19 [4th] => 26 ) [Monday] => Array ( [1st] => 6 [2nd] => 13 [3rd] => 20 [4th] => 27 ) [Tuesday] => Array ( [1st] => 7 [2nd] => 14 [3rd] => 21 [4th] => 28 ) [Wednesday] => Array ( [1st] => 8 [2nd] => 15 [3rd] => 22 [4th] => 29 ) [Thursday] => Array ( [1st] => 9 [2nd] => 16 [3rd] => 23 [4th] => 30 ) )
```

I've figured out that I can print each of my arrays out with     `print_r($March['Friday']);`

But that only gives me this

```
Array ( [1st] => 3 [2nd] => 10 [3rd] => 17 [4th] => 24 [5th] => 31 )
```

which is not the same as this

```
[Friday] => Array ( [1st] => 3 [2nd] => 10 [3rd] => 17 [4th] => 24 [5th] => 31 )
```

plz send help, have been staring at w3 for hours.

Comment: You don't use `print_r()` for this. You must write your own formatting code.

Comment: The format you want isn't a valid PHP array. Do you just need to display it as a string? Or do you want to be able to further manipulate the data?

Comment: I will need to manipulate the data, this is a homework assignment and my next task is to loop through the array with foreach, and print out like so"   3 is the 1st Friday in March.
10 is the 2nd Friday in March.
17 is the 3rd Friday in March.
24 is the 4th Friday in March.
31 is the 5th Friday in March.

4 is the 1st Saturday in March.
11 is the 2nd Saturday in March.
18 is the 3rd Saturday in March.
"

Comment: There is learning and then there is getting stuck on a simple formatting issue for hours causing a setback that could otherwise be put to good use (actual learning). I suppose when you were learning to code you didn't get stuck? and consequently seek help? Similarly, what if I excluded the homework part of that response. Does it make it so much different? its not like my question is "how do I declare a variable". I just need help with formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achive this what you write in comment you can use below loop:

```
foreach($March as $nameOfDay => $dayArray ){
    foreach($dayArray as $key => $val){
        echo $val.' is the '.$key.' '.$nameOfDay.' in March. ';
    }
}
```